# How to run Keras models with AVX2 support

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, avx2

I need to measure execution time for prediction per image by running models such as mobilenet2 and densnet121.

First, I just run my python code with stock tensorflow.

```
start = time.time()
out = m.predict(val)
end = time.time()

print("model: densenet")
print ("time: ", (end - start)/batch_size)
```

where batch_size used to avoid prediction overhead time.

I've gotten followed output:

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
model: mobilenet2
time: 0.24023537635803222
model: densenet
time: 1.045912742614746
```

Then I download [tensorflow-build wheel](https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build) and install wheel using `python -m pip`

Current message:

```
# AVX2 message does not appear anymore
model: mobilenet2
time:  0.16217999935150146
model: densenet
time:  0.6216100001335144
```

Is there a "right" way to do this, because it looks like avx2 doesn't accelerate prediction so much?

Comment: Relative improvement is 40-50%, I wouldn't call this bad at all.

Comment: Yes, maybe, but it's still slow.

Comment: Then what is exactly the question? It is not clear now, it is running with AVX2 and there is an improvement with it.

Comment: I thought that improvement will be much greater. Does it because I use python keras API? And If I want greater acceleration I should write tensorflow code and use things like MKL?